# How can I make mobile version of an existing web site that has subdomains?

Tags: asp.net, mobile

We have a website which has subdomains. The home page url will be http://www.mywebsite.com user will have to select an url in the home page which will take the user to the subdomain url i.e http://link1.mywebsite.com.

We are trying to have the minimized version of the website for mobile. Like youtube (http://www.youtube.com), we are thinking to have suddomain (http://m.youtube.com)

Is it possible to have http://m.link1.mywebsite.com ? If yes, is it possible to do the redirection in IIS based the device used to access the web site?

**Edit:**

In Global.aspx of http://www.mywebsite.com, We need to redirect to http://mobile.mywebsite.com (hosted as separate web application) if the request is from mobile device. Will this work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all its possible to have a sub-domain to look a different asp.net application, or different sub-directory, or even easiest, to see this sub-domain and rewrite the path to give different content.

For example, it's very easy on the `Global.asax`: you can read the host, and if its start with this domain, you make a simple rewrite path to a sub-directory code, e.g to `/mobile/`

Now to redirect your users you must look at two things. One if the device is mobile, and second its screen dimensions.

As mobile you need to serve a limited bandwidth content, with minimum resources because of the bandwidth cost on mobiles.

With screen dimensions you need to setup the pages.

There are some libraries that make this detection and you search them on web and find the one that fits your needs.

https://www.google.com/search?q=mobile+detection+asp.net